# On button click reload content (ajax) in tab

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jquery ui tabs. Every tab get content via ajax load. How can I reload content in active tab when I click the button or when the form in content is submitted.

So far I've got this.. (that works).

HTML

```
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>        
        <li><a href="check-in-t1.php">1</a></li>
        <li><a href="check-in-t2.php">2</a></li>
        <li><a href="check-in-t3.php">3</a></li>
        <li><a href="check-in-t4.php">4</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>

<a href="#" class="btn btn-osvezi2" id="btn-osvezi2">Refresh</a>
```

JS

```
<script>
        $( function() {
            $( "#tabs" ).tabs({
                beforeLoad: function( event, ui ) {
                    ui.jqXHR.fail(function() {
                        ui.panel.html(
                            "Vsebine ni mogoče prikazati. Poskusite kasneje." );
                    });
                }
            });         
        } );
</script>
```

Comment: How often does the content change? Could you load the content for a tab into a variable and just call that each time the tab is active?

Answer (score 0):

The widget provides the `load` method ( https://api.jqueryui.com/tabs/#method-load ) specifically for this purpose:

```
$("#btn-osvezi2").click(function() {
    var index = $("#tabs").tabs("option", "active");
    $("#tabs").tabs("load", index);
});
```

Comment: I've tried this code and I get this message: TypeError: $(...).tabs is not a function.. 

Which is weird because my code above also includes "tabs" and it is working.

Comment: That's probably because the code is calling it before loading the library

Comment: this doesn't work anymore with latest jquery-ui, if the tab was already loaded it does nothing, can i invalidate content so that it gets reloaded?

Comment: @user311174 It hasn't been changed as far as I can tell. Could you make a [mcve]? If the problem is sufficiently long/different perhaps post it as a new question

Comment: i get no errors, but the tab doesn't get reloaded, i opened the new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43588768/tabs-load-doesnt-reload-content-in-jquery-ui-1-2-1)

Comment: I can't reproduce the behaviour in the linked question, which looks rather unrelated. Again, it would be helpful if you could make a [mcve]. None of jQueryUI's `widget` widgets do (nor did), to my recollection, any caching by default