# tabs load doesn't reload content in jquery ui 1.2.1

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

load used to work with former versions of this library:

> $("#myTabs").tabs("load", index);

According to the docs, this should load the remote tab. Yet once the tab has been loaded it doesn't load anymore.

Also, disable the cache doesnt' work anymore:

> $( "#myTabs" ).tabs({  cache: false    });

How may i emulate this former behaviour?, this breaks a lot of code in my app

Comment: Caching would not have been enabled by default. Could you make a [mcve]? What do the AJAX messages look like?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in the changelog:

http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#deprecated-ajaxoptions-and-cache-options-added-beforeload-event